# Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

After integrates python in Android studio by chaquopy, Can't run python file when import opencv-python
Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

build.gradle file in android studio.

```
    python {
        version "3.11"
    }

    python {
        buildPython "C:/Python311/python.exe"
    }

    python {
        pip {
            install "numpy"
            install "opencv-python"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            python.srcDir "src/main/python"
        }
    }
}
```

```
MainActivity.class: 

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (!Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this));
        }

        val py = Python.getInstance()
        val module = py.getModule("script")

    }
}
```

python file: script.py

import numpy as np

import cv2

text = "ABC"

num = 55

Answer (score 0):

Chaquopy currently only provides OpenCV for Python 3.8, so try changing the `python { version }` setting.

To be notified when this changes, please subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/779).

Comment: Process 'command 'C:/Python/Python38/python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1. Build failed after I changed version python3.8

Comment: @TheSonHoang: Please create an issue on the [Chaquopy GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues), and include the full build log.